# Interpolating and pass Argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to interpolate my Javascript Code with a Ruby Function.
For example:

```
def find_house name
   ......
end

def map_houses
 %{
    function() {
       var name = this.name;
       var house_data = #{find_house(this.name)};
       ............
     }
  }
end
```

**But, it doesn't work like this, i get an error for this line:**

```
 var house_data = #{find_house(this.name)};
```

It says `this.name` is `Undefinded`.

**How can I pass a javascript argument to this function?** Thanks

Comment: Is "interpolate" the correct word here? I'm not familiar with its use in this context. Do you mean you want to translate your Javascript into Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to interpolate the value of `find_house` into javascript, which will be executed elsewhere.  It looks pretty close, but you do need to make a couple of changes.

```
def map_houses
 %Q{
    function() {
       var name = this.name;
       var house_data = "#{find_house(this.name)}";
       ............
     }
  }
end
```

`%Q` allows you to interpolate into a multi-line string, whereas `%q` does not.  It's kind of like the difference between `''` and `""`.  The other change is that you will still want to wrap the interpolated value in `""` so that the resulting javascript is properly wrapped in a string, assuming that `var house_data` is a string.  If it's supposed to be a JSON object, then you'll want to remove the quotes and ensure that you're calling `to_json` on whatever value is interpolated there.

#### Edit

You can probably just drop the quotes wrapping the interpolation and call `to_json` on any value, and it will interpolate correctly.  `"some string".to_json  #=> "\"some string\""`, which interpolates to `"some string"`, for example.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! But I still get the same error `undefined local variable or method `this'` because `this.name` is not recognized as a javascript argument that shoulb be passed to the ruby function! What can I do?

Comment: Yeah, your javascript is not being run within the Ruby context, so Ruby has no idea what `this.name` is.  (I didn't even realize that you were trying to do that above... sorry.)  You need to have some other method of passing JS information to your Ruby code, like via AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks, but This javascript code is in the backend!

Comment: It's still executing outside of the context of Ruby, unless you're using `execjs` or something similar to pass data to a javascript context.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  Where does the javascript get executed?  No matter what, you're going to have to have some kind of interface to transfer data from your JS context to your Ruby context.  Via the web, that's usually done via AJAX or web sockets.  If your javascript code is running on the backend, node or something else, then you can use TCP or something else.